# How do I find the end of a 20 minute MP3 and stop it in AS3 (Flash CS6)?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, audio, mp3

I've used Flash before but new to AS3. I'm designing a touch based play/pause button for an MP3 that lasts 20 minutes for an Android app, but unable to find the actual end of the MP3 file and make it stop. How can I scroll to the very end of my very, very long MP3 on the timeline to do this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem.  Are you trying to programatically stop the mp3 file from playing?  What methods are you using to play the sounds?  `SoundMixer.stopAll();`?

Comment: As DaOrge suggested, if your sound is on your timeline use `SoundMixer.stopAll();` on the frame where the sound ends on your timeline. Or you could also use `SoundMixer.soundTransform.volume = 0;` just to mute all of your sounds.

Answer (score 0):

You should simply call on Your Sound object function :

```
var minute:int = 20;
sound.play(minute * 60 * 1000);
```

this will seek to 20 minute of Your sound .

Comment: Many thanks for your time and helpful advice. Haven't had enough time yet to continue with this particular issue, as I'm still stumbling through some others.

Wanted to thank you regardless;-)